# The script is not changing the image after once

Tags: javascript, html

The script is changing the image only once. Then it is not working at all.

SCRIPT:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function change_image(){
        if (window.document.pic.src='images/NAV_OFFhome_trans.png')
        {
            window.document.pic.src='images/NAV_OFFhist_trans.png';
        }
        else if (window.document.pic.src='images/NAV_OFFhist_trans.png')
        {
            window.document.pic.src='images/NAV_OFFhome_trans.png';
        }
    }
</script>
```

HTML:

```
<div id="main" >
<img src="images/NAV_OFFhome_trans.png" name="pic" onclick="change_image()"     style="position:absolute;"/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your if/else if statements, you're setting the src instead of checking against the value.  Make sure to use `==` instead of `=`.

As such:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function change_image(){
        if (window.document.pic.src == 'images/NAV_OFFhome_trans.png')
        {
            window.document.pic.src = 'images/NAV_OFFhist_trans.png';
        }
        else if (window.document.pic.src == 'images/NAV_OFFhist_trans.png')
        {
            window.document.pic.src = 'images/NAV_OFFhome_trans.png';
        }
    }
</script>
```

Here's an example for good measure: http://jsfiddle.net/rd6dL/

Comment: It is working in fiddle but I don't know why it is not working for me in a new php file here.

Comment: Have you made sure to change only the if statement's operator?  Can you create a working fiddle with the fully URL for each of your images so that I can review it?